# Nested classes in form validation

Tags: c#, blazor-server-side

In my Blazor EditForm I do server side validation like this:

```
public class NewProgramInput
{
    [Required]
    public string? Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string? Email { get; set; }
}

<EditForm Model="@NewProgramInput" OnValidSubmit="(() => SubmitForm())">
    <div>
        <InputText class="input" @bind-Value="NewProgramInput.Name" />
        <ValidationMessage For="(() => NewProgramInput.Name)"></ValidationMessage>
    </div>
    <div>
        <InputText class="input" @bind-Value="NewProgramInput.Email" />
        <ValidationMessage For="(() => NewProgramInput.Email)"></ValidationMessage>
    </div>
</EditForm>
```

My real form is way larger than this and I'd like to split it up in multiple steps.

I could make `NewProgramInput1` with properties, `NewProgramInput2` with properties and so on... but I thought that I could maybe use nested classes like this, as I find it more readable:

```
public class NewProgramInput
{
    public class Step1
    {
        [Required]
        public string? Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Step2
    {
        [Required]
        public string? Email { get; set; }
    }
}

@if (Step == 1)
{
    <EditForm Model="@NewProgramInput.Step1" OnValidSubmit="(() => SubmitForm())">
        <div>
            <InputText class="input" @bind-Value="NewProgramInput.Step1.Name" />
            <ValidationMessage For="(() => NewProgramInput.Step1.Name)"></ValidationMessage>
        </div>
    </EditForm>
}

@if (Step == 2)
{
    <EditForm Model="@NewProgramInput.Step2" OnValidSubmit="(() => SubmitForm())">
        <div>
            <InputText class="input" @bind-Value="NewProgramInput.Step2.Email" />
            <ValidationMessage For="(() => NewProgramInput.Step2.Email)"></ValidationMessage>
        </div>
    </EditForm>
}
```

But that gives me the error:

`NewProgramInput.Step1 is a type, which is not valid in the given context.`

Is it just not possible or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to use the nested classes as if they were instances of the class. You need to instantiate them to use them in Razor components.

```
public class NewProgramInput
{
    public Step1 step1 { get; set; } = new Step1();
    public Step2 step2 { get; set; } = new Step2();

    public class Step1
    {
        [Required]
        public string? Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Step2
    {
        [Required]
        public string? Email { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And then use the instances:

```
@if (Step == 1)
{
    <EditForm Model="@NewProgramInput.step1" OnValidSubmit="(() => SubmitForm())">
        <div>
            <InputText class="input" @bind-Value="NewProgramInput.step1.Name" />
            <ValidationMessage For="(() => NewProgramInput.step1.Name)"></ValidationMessage>
        </div>
    </EditForm>
}
```